# Edittext at bottom should not get focus if focus is on edittext at top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have two edittext one at top and other at bottom.When i type in top edittext, the edittext at bottom gets focus and come up.Is there any way that edittext at bottom does not get focus

Comment: post ur xml and activity

Answer (score 0):

in menefest:
windowSoftInputMode flag to "adjustPan"

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

and on top edittext add requestFocus

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/ed_temp"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
   android:singleLine="true"><requestFocus/></EditText>
```